# Issues With Block Title in Django Template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a custom Title to my product pages using the block title tag in Django.

I have a view function to return data to a template for the product page:

```
def deal_by_detail(request, slug):
    deal_detail = Deal.objects.filter(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'deals/deal_detail.html', {'deal_detail': deal_detail})
```

and URL for the deal_detail page:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>.*)/$', deal_by_detail, name='deal_detail'),
```

In my 'deal_detail.html' page I have successfully displayed all the information from a particular product... like so:

```
{% for deal in deal_detail%}
{{ deal.title}}
{{ deal.price}}
{% endfor %}
```

However i'm having an issue with the block title.  Since it comes before the aforementioned loop, i realize I can't reference the title like so:

```
{% block title %}{{deal.title}}{% endblock %}
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
{% block title %}{{deal_detail.title}}{% endblock %}
```

But that doesn't work either --nor does just `{{ title }}`

I also experimented with a duplicate of the other loop and that doesn't work either.

Here is what I have on the base template page that is extended from this deal_detail template:

```
<title>My Site - {% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
```

Just kind of stumped and not sure if I need a class based view or something I'm totally missing here.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which `deal`'s title do you want to use? If you want the first, try this: `deal_detail.0.title`.

Comment: maybe that's the issue here--i just want to use the title that is passed via a clicked link from the home page--which would include a passed 'slug' variable.  I think i might need to rework the view and not have a loop for the other variables.

Comment: wait but that does work!  i'm really confused as to why it does--each page that I click on it is generating the correct title, but in my mind I would have expected it to be producing the same title on each page.

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, the links you are clicking on specifies the slug. That slug specifies the `Deal`. The view includes the specified `Deal` in the context and you access that `Deals` title. If there is only one Deal with the specified slug, you could use `get` instead of `filter` and drop the loop.

Comment: yep--that's exactly what I needed to do.  thank you very much for the advice--works perfect now.